# Python requests does not return same result as web browser

Tags: python, api, python-requests

Ok, so here is my problem. When I do browser call for API (that client gave me):

https://<some.web_adress>/status.asmx/Fin?gt=14046.40&key=<auth_key>&cash=notes&date=2020-06-25+15%3A47%3A01&receipt_number=748&type=collect&sum=0.00&pos=003-480

the result is: `{ "0":"Success"}`

However, when I do the same call with `python requests` library (I hope it same call):

```
    event_data = {'key': <exactly_the_same_auth_key>,
                 'pos': DEVICE_ID,
                 'type': 'monthlybalance',
                 'total': close_data['overall']['price'],
                 'cash': close_data['overall']['price_c'],
                 'cards': close_data['overall']['price_cl'],
                 'coinbox': sorted_cash_data['coinbox'],
                 'notebox': sorted_cash_data['notebox'],
                 'coindispenser': sorted_cash_data['coindispenser'],
                 'notedispenser': sorted_cash_data['notedispenser'],
                 'startdate': close_data['header']['from'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                 'enddate': close_data['header']['to'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                 'receipt_number': 'none',
                 'gt': self.get_grand_total()}

    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(event_data), timeout=5)
```

The result is: `{ "1":"KEY can not be empty"}`

Which, is the result they made, BUT its not the same result as WEB call, and it is clear, that the API did not take the key properly.

However, I was trying the whole day today, to find a way how to print raw URL call, requests do. Unsucesfully.
I was also been trying various methods of passing the key to requests:

1. Put it into headers - not worked `header={'key': <exactly_the_same_auth_key>},`
2. Put it into auth - not worked `auth=(<exactly_the_same_auth_key>, '')`

I am almost sure that requests is making up the ULR wrong (because it works in browser) but I have no idea how to fix it. Or how to check, where the problem is.

Comment: the problem is here `r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(event_data), timeout=5)`, `post` is not expecting its data in `json` format, but in `url-encoded` format, so either change the request and encoding method (eg to `get`) and/or change data encoding appropriately

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between *parameters* in a request and the *body* of a request. What you're doing here is sending the values in the request *body*, but the URL at the top is passing the values in as URL parameters. Try this:

```py
event_data = {'key': <exactly_the_same_auth_key>,
                 'pos': DEVICE_ID,
                 'type': 'monthlybalance',
                 'total': close_data['overall']['price'],
                 'cash': close_data['overall']['price_c'],
                 'cards': close_data['overall']['price_cl'],
                 'coinbox': sorted_cash_data['coinbox'],
                 'notebox': sorted_cash_data['notebox'],
                 'coindispenser': sorted_cash_data['coindispenser'],
                 'notedispenser': sorted_cash_data['notedispenser'],
                 'startdate': close_data['header']['from'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                 'enddate': close_data['header']['to'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                 'receipt_number': 'none',
                 'gt': self.get_grand_total()}

    r = requests.post(url, params=event_data, timeout=5)
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it returned same result: `{ "1":"KEY can not be empty"}`

Comment: It's hard to say then without specifics. It's not possible for people to test out what's going wrong without a URL or possible API key, since this problem is very specific to the current situation.

Comment: Well, I cannot provide key and URL for security reasons.

Comment: In that case you're likely on your own. Good luck!